# PHP & MySQL - Compare IPs that are stored

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a system to store the last logged on IP, and to compare it to the current IP, then do some functions later on down the road, but currently, I cannot compare them without going to the last else statement. Here's the code.

```
<?php

$userToPull = $session->userinfo['username'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$userToPull'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);      

            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                    $userToShow = $row[25];
                    $IPtoVerify = $row[26];

                    }

$lastActivity = RelativeTime($userToShow);
$currIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

/*

Shows Partner Stuff

}elseif(!$session->isAdmin()){

echo "<div style='text-align:right;' id='homebox'";
echo "<b>Partner Total:</b> ".$database->getNumMembers()."<br>";
echo $database->num_active_users." partners logged in and ";
echo $database->num_active_guests." guests viewing the site.<br><br>";
echo "</div>";

*/


if(!$IPtoVerify == $currIP){

echo "<div style='text-align:right; background-color: #FAAAB3' id='homebox_partner'";
echo "<b>You are logged on from an unrecognized location.</b><br>";
echo "You will be sent a notification for security purposes.";
echo "<br>This location will automatically be remembered.";
echo "</div><br>";

}elseif($IPtoVerify == $currIP){

echo "<div style='text-align:right;' id='homebox_partner'";
echo "<b>You are logged on from a recognized location.</b><br>";
echo "Your IP is ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo "<br>Your last login was approximately ".$lastActivity;
echo "</div><br>";

}else{

echo "<div style='text-align:right;' id='homebox_partner'";
echo "<b>An error has occurred.</b><br>";
echo "</div><br>";


}

?>
```

The only thing not working is the `if(!$IPtoVerify == $currIP){` if statement.

The IP is stored in the normal fashion, and echo's like: 100.100.100.100. (normal fashion)

Maybe I am not comparing them right, but it has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't do what you think:

```
if (!$IPtoVerify == $currIP) {
```

PHP interprets it as:

```
if ((!$IPtoVerify) == $currIP) {
```

You will want to write it as:

```
if ($IPtoVerify != $currIP) {
```

Comment: This worked! Should I just use one equal sign for my elseif as well?

Comment: No. != means 'is not' equal to, and == means 'is' equal to. One equals sign (=) is an assignment, not an equality check. You'd use a single equals for assigning a value to a variable e.g. `$x = 1;`

Comment: No, your `elseif` is okay, but you can replace it with and `else` and remove the last `else` statement. That's because the two IP's are either equal or not equal to each other .. there's not a third option :)

Comment: Great! Thanks guys, a ton of help! When should I use the != versus the original way I had it, when there is numbers?

Comment: The way you had it `(!$IPtoVerify == $currIP)` is semantically incorrect. What I mean by that is this: The ! sign in the manner you originally used it is for negating things. It should be used on booleans only, no other type. So what the ! does in the case you originally used it, it is trying to change an IP address to true or false. It makes no sense see. The way it should be used is to negate a value, so a true boolean would become false and a false boolean would become true. If this still isn't making sense, take a look at this: `if(!($IPtoVerify == $currIP)){//Executes when IPs are diff}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `($IPtoVerify !== $currIP)` instead of `(!$IPtoVerify == $currIP)`

Comment: close, but it should be `($IPtoVerify != $currIP)`

Comment: @LiamGeorgeBetsworth, doesn't matter. both are strings so in this case _!==_ and _!=_ are the same

Comment: != and !== would yield the same result here, but they aren't the same thing. Checking if `a !== b` is overkill in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
!$IPtoVerify == $currIP
```

means

```
0==$currIP,
```

because it first validates

```
`!$IPtoVerify`
```

which always returns 0 unless $IPtoVerify is 1.

Add additional brackets like

```
if(!($IPtoVerify == $currIP))...
```

to solve the issue.